# Nativescript Audio: Access Player across pages?

Tags: nativescript

I am using the [nativescript-audio plugin](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio) for my iOS angular NS app.

I want to start playing an audio file on one page, navigate to a different page, and manipulate the audio player from that second page. So I need to access the player instance on a page that is different than where the instance was created.

For example, start playing audio on Page 1, and then pause the player on Page 2.

How can I do this?

I have tried saving the player instance in local storage to access later, but local storage saves items as strings, so I need to convert the player instance to a string, which doesn't work.

Comment: With angular you could put the player in a service (Injectable) and access it app wide that way.

Comment: That worked. Thanks very much. I'll write up a summary for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brad Martin recommended, it works to put the player in an injectable Angular service and access it app wide. So, for example:

**Create the Service:**

app.module.ts:

```
import { AudioService } from "./audio-service"

@NgModule({
...
  providers: [
     AudioService  //registers the service with the provider's metadata
  ]   
})
```

audio-service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
    import { TNSPlayer } from "nativescript-audio"

    @Injectable()

    export class AudioService {
     private _player: TNSPlayer;
     playEvent = new EventEmitter<any>()

     constructor() {}

      playAudio(audioFilePath){
        this._player = new TNSPlayer();
        this._player.initFromFile({
           audioFile: audioFilePath,
           loop: false,
        }).then(()=>{
            this._player.play()
            this.playEvent.emit('File is playing now')
         })
      }

      pausePlayer(){
        this._player.pause()
      }
    }
```

**Access the Service:**

cool-component.ts:

```
import {OnInit} from @angular/core"
import { AudioService } from "~/audio-service"
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page"  

@Component({...})

export class CoolComponent implements OnInit {
  public getPlay: any;

  constructor(private _audioService: AudioService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getPlay = this._audioService.playEvent.subscribe((value)=>{
      console.log(value) //when audio is playing, should say 'File is playing now'
    }
    this.page.on('navigatingFrom', (data) => {
      if (this.getPlay){
         this.getPlay.unsubscribe()  //unsubscribe from service emitter when exit the page--to avoid multiplying the subscription every time you go to this page
      })
  }

  playAudioFromService(audioFilePathDetail){
    this._audioService.playAudio(audioFilePathDetail)
  } 

  pauseAudioFromService(){
    this._audioService.pausePlayer()
  }

}
```